# IOS Add observer for delegate function (like ) scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:

Tags: ios, object, delegates, uiscrollview

Do you know how to add an observer (or a notification) to a standard delegate method call ? (I know this is a little weird/ not what observers were intended for)

I'm ultimately trying to catch the page change of a scrollview in a uiscrollview category method.

I can observe the content offset of a scrollview like this
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentOffset" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew) context:NULL];

,but rather than being notified when the contentOffset is changed, I'd prefer to be notified when scrolling has ended or deceleration will begin.

I'm working on some advanced functionality for scrollviews (meaning I already know I can catch delegate call by just assigning a delegate)

any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need a notification for some reason, why not implement the delegate methods for which you want to be notified and fire off your own notifications from them?

Comment: I am trying to basically add a feature to ALL of my scrollviews (via a category method), but without subclassing, or implementing delegate functions everywhere

Comment: How about KVO-ing tracking/dragging/decelerating properties? It might help if you describe what kind of functionality you're trying to implement.

Comment: ultimately, I'm implementing a lazy loading structure into my custom built scrollviews.. my plan of attack is to catch when paging changes, then build the new views, and destroy the old views (outside of the viewable bounds of the person.. where im at right now, i have an observer that is being called (corresponding to when the content offset is changed, but it (of course) gets called way more often then i would like (as i only need to catch the page change)

Comment: It sound like observing `tracking` and `decelerating` is what you need then. When both get changed to NO, you know the scrolling stopped for sure.

Comment: i tried to an observer for decelerating.. [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"decelerating" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew) context:NULL]; but it never gets called (i would guess because its a boolean ??)